# What happens if the power goes out during bitcoin mining process and system shuts off?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am in an area where there is power outage. I want to know, what will happen to bitcoin or my wallet or anything. Just need the basic information here.

Answer (score 2):

The wallet will be safe. (Unless your drive becomes corrupt and you have no backup of the wallet anywhere else)

Nothing happens to the BTC you already have.

The Blockchain will be out of sync until you sync it again.

If you were about to find the block, it will be lost and the reward will not be awarded.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume a properly backed-up wallet.  Otherwise it changes the question to something like "if I lose my wallet, do I lose my wallet?".  This question is about the mining process and power loss.  Whether data loss can cause bitcoin loss is a different question.

Comment: @abelenky added the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running a full node then it doesn't matter. Since you are asking you probably are not running a full node.

Answer (score 0):

Although your bitcoin is completely safe on the decentralized storage of the blockchain, the real risk is losing the private keys in your wallet due to hard drive corruption or failure during a power outage.

Once private keys are gone, they are gone forever.

It would be prudent to make a backup copy of your wallet, or your private keys that you can keep safe if your hard drive is lost for any reason.